# Calculate e with threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, factorial

I am trying to calculate the neper number e in java with threads.

I am using the convergent row sum((3-4*k^2)/(2*k+1)!).

The user can determine how many threads the program will be using and how many iterations will be done.

Every thread does a sum of 1/numberOfThreads part of the interval. I have to do this as faster as possible.

But I am having trouble with the factorial function; In the output file i get 0E-20 as a result ... I'll be very thankful if someone can help me with this problem.

```
public class CalculateE {

    static BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    static BigDecimal f = BigDecimal.ONE;
    static BigDecimal f1 = BigDecimal.ONE;
    static BigDecimal f_rev = BigDecimal.ONE;
    static BigDecimal fact = BigDecimal.ONE;
    static BigDecimal fact_rev = BigDecimal.ONE;

    public static BigDecimal factorial(int x){
        BigDecimal prod = BigDecimal.ONE;
        for (int i=x; i>1; i--){
            prod = prod.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
        }
        return prod;
    }

    public static Runnable getRunner(final int from, final int to, int iter){
        Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                for (int i=from; i<to && i<=iter/2; i++){
                    if(i == from){

                    fact = factorial(2*i+1);

                    }else{
                        fact=fact.multiply(BigDecimal
                                            .valueOf((2*i)*(2*i+1)));

                    }

                    e = e.add(BigDecimal
                                .valueOf(3 - 4*Math.pow(i, 2))
                                .divide(fact, 
                                        new MathContext(10000,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)));

                } 
                addResult(e); 
            }
        };
        return runner;
    }

    //public static synchronized void addResult(BigDecimal e){
    //  result = result.add(e);
    //}
    public static synchronized void addResult(BigDecimal e){
        result = result.add(e);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Default values
        // Number of Threads used
        int NumOfth = 1;
        // Number of Iterations
        int p = 1000;
        //Quiet mode
        Boolean quiet = false;
        //Output file
        String nameOffile = "result.txt";


        // A check for command line arguments
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i].equals("-p")) {
                p = new Integer(args[i + 1]);
            }
            if (args[i].equals("-t")){
                NumOfth = new Integer(args[i+1]);
            }
            if (args[i].equals("-q")){
                quiet = true;
                System.out.println("Quiet mode enabled.");
            }
            if (args[i].equals("-o")){
                nameOffile = args[i+1];
            }
        }

        //Check for correct input
        if (p <= 0 || NumOfth <= 0 ||  args.length > 7) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Args are not correct!!!");
        } else{

            long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (quiet == false){
                System.out.println("Threads used in current run: " + NumOfth);
            }

            Runnable r[] = new Runnable[NumOfth];
            Thread[] myThreads; 
            myThreads = new Thread[NumOfth];
            int from = 0;
            int to = (p/(NumOfth*2));

            int interval = to - from;

            for (int i = 0; i<NumOfth; i++){
                //Create a runnable object
                r[i] = getRunner(from, to, p);

                // Create our threads over our runnable object

                Thread thrd = new Thread(r[i]);
                if (quiet == false){
                    System.out.println("Thread <" + i + "> created.");
                }

                thrd.start();

                if (quiet == false){
                    System.out.println("Thread <" + i + "> started.");
                }
                myThreads[i] = thrd;
                from = to + 1;
                to = to + interval+1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i<NumOfth; i++){
                try{
                    //System.out.println("Thread <" + i + "> started.");
                    myThreads[i].join();
                }   catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(quiet == false){
                System.out.println("e = " + result.setScale(20, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
            }

            //Write the result to a file
            //File myfile = new File(nameOffile);
            Writer writer = null;
            try{

                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(nameOffile), "utf-8"));

                writer.write("" + result.setScale(20, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
            } catch(IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try { 
                    // close the file
                    writer.close(); 
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        //ignore
                    }
            }
            //Current time
            long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //Time for execution
            long diff = stop - start1;
            System.out.println(diff + " ms");
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much is 0 / number of threads? `int from = 0;` divide by zero problem?

Comment: Are you sure you can use this sum for calculate e? IMHO your numerator is always negative

Comment: number of threads can't be 0. And i don't divide by from. From-to is the interval which is calculated by 1 thread. I am sure that this is the sum. It's my course project.

Comment: You start with numOfTh=1 and later, you say int to = (p/(NumOfth*2)); so to=500... Also, you set from = to + 1; in your loop - assume that you want to use 2 threads for p=1000, to is 250 and in your loop, getRunner is called like this: getRunner(0, 250, 1000) and getRunnter(1, 501, 1000)

Comment: The default value of num of th is 1. Its value is taken from the command line. If there's no such value inputted the default value is 1. I divide p/(numofthr*2) cuz i want a single thread to perform actions on two intervals - from-to and (p-to)-(p-from) but i haven't wrote this yet. 
The other theory : i set from = to + 1 . So if I start from 0 to 250 then from takes 251 value and to=to + interval + 1 = 501.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a very dumb mistake... I do not set fact = 1 before the loop starts...